# Why do I have an undefined variable in my template

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pdo

I have the following Action within a controller. When I go to the corresponding View, I get the following PHP error.

```
public function viewallpolice($id=NULL) {
    $customer = $this->Session->read('customer_id'); 
    
    if ($customer>0) {
        $this->loadModel('Policy');
        $results = $this->Policy->find(
            'all',
            array('conditions' => array('customer_id' => $customer))
        );

        $this->set('results', $this->Policy->read(null, $id));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('error');
    }
}
```

view all police code:

```
<?php foreach ($user as $result) ?>
<p>Customer Name /Mobile : <?php echo $result['Policy']['customer_name']; ?></p>
```

Error:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: user [APP\View\User\viewallpolice.ctp, line 1]
>
> Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\User\viewallpolice.ctp, line 1]
>
> Customer Name /Mobile :
>
> Notice (8): Undefined variable: result [APP\View\User\viewallpolice.ctp, line 2]

Comment: Please title your questions something useful in future.

Comment: `Undefined variable: user` - the controller code makes no attempt to _set_ a variable named user - not sure why you're expecting that to work ..?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using cakephp 3 .
In your controller :

```
      public function viewallpolice($id=NULL) {
        $customer = $this->Session->read('customer_id'); 

        if ($customer>0) {
            $this->loadModel('Policy');
            $results = $this->Policy->find('all',['conditions' =>['customer_id' => $customer]] )->toArray();;
            $this->set('results', $results);
            //use pr($result) to print the result array
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('error');
        }
    }
```

In your Template if the customer_name field is in the table policy :

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
<p>Customer Name /Mobile : <?= $result['customer_name']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: if my ans is working for you then please click the accept option

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` loop is incorrect. See the [documentation for `foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for more information.

Since you are setting `$results` in your controller code, you'd want something like:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
<p>Customer Name /Mobile : <?php echo $result['Policy']['customer_name']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined variable: results [APP\View\User\viewallpolice.ctp, line 1]

Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\User\viewallpolice.ctp, line 1]

Comment: Are you sure `results` is being set? Also do you want results to be set from the `Policy->read` function call, or from your `find` function?

Honestly, you didn't provide too much information. Just pasting code with an error message isn't the greatest approach. For starters, you could `debug($customer)` within your controller to see what value it is (aka, is it greater than `0`?). In your URL, are you passing in a valid **Policy** `$id`? There are a lot of questions you can answer, but those should be a good starting point.

Comment: sorry sir. Actually  m fresher so i d'nt know for whole procedure.i will check again..and thnks